# Webpage login not working Using excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, internet-explorer, vba

I am working on project to download the dump from website and save it on the path specified using Excel vba.

Code is working perfectly when u do the debug or execute line by line by pressing "F8".

but when you execute the whole program by pressing "F5" or clicking on button after assigning macro to it. its not working.

need your precious advise to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance,
Prasanna

VBA Code used to login.

```
Sub Login()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer


MyURL = "URL"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.Navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True

Do
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
Loop Until MyBrowser.READYSTATE = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
    HTMLDoc.all.Country_Code.Value = "Country_Code"
    HTMLDoc.all.Login.Value = "UserName" 
    HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "Password" 
    HTMLDoc.all.Item("B1").Click

        For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("B1")
            If MyHTML_Element.Type = "button" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
        Next

End sub
```

Sample HTML code of webpage for login.

```
                <table border=0>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Country:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="country_code" maxlength=2
                                 onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();Form1_action(this.value)">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Language:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="idioma"  disabled  >
                                <option value="uk|es" onblur="document.Form1.login.focus()">ENGLISH</option>
<option value="sp|es" onblur="document.Form1.login.focus()">SPANISH</option>
<option value="fr|en-us" onblur="document.Form1.login.focus()">FRENCH</option>
<option value="it|en-us" onblur="document.Form1.login.focus()">ITALIAN</option>
<option value="de|de" onblur="document.Form1.login.focus()">GERMAN</option>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Login:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="login" maxlength=10 value=""  disabled >
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="passwd" maxlength=10 value=""  disabled  onkeypress="var okp=(event.which)?event.which:event.keyCode; if(okp==13) SiteRedirect(this.form)">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

                <br>

                <center>
                    <input type="button" name="B1" value="Sign In"
                        onclick="SiteRedirect()"
                         disabled 
                        style="width:80pt"
                        >

                </center>
```

Comment: change your do loop where you tell the code to wait while IE loads to `Loop While MyBrowser.ReadyState <> 4 or MyBrowser.Busy`

Comment: Hi Scott thank you for the reply... i tried the above code but still its not working... What i guess is that vba code execution is more speedy than IE webpage load time... do i need to increase the time span of wait function...??? Will it help...???

Comment: Yes, the code execution is in VBA is *independent* of the browser load time, so you have to account for that, as you already are. Increasing the wait time inside the loop won't matter matter, because it will keep looping while IE is not ready. I am posting the code I use for this in an answer. It works for me quit well in an application I frequently use.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I use to allow IE to load in an application that frequently works with webpages in IE. I have come to this after a lot of trial and error and it works consistently now - though I have seen many ways to accomplish this.

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Sub IEWait(IE As Object)
'assumes IE is loaded as InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE
    Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: Sleep (100): Loop
End With

End Sub
```

You can add this to your code by

1. Placing the Public Declare at the top of your module window before any `Sub` are defined.
2. Incorporating it into your code as shown below.

Code:

```
With MyBrowser
     .Silent = True 
     .Navigate MyURL
     .Visible = True

     Do While .Busy or .Readystate <> 4: Sleep (100): Loop

     Set HTMLDoc = .document

     '... rest of code

End With
```

Comment: Let me try with your code by this week end... and i'll let you know the results by Sunday.... thank you again scoot... happy weekend... and merry Christmas.... in advance....

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too @Prasanna! Happy weekend and may the joy in your heart spread throughout you and your life this holiday season and beyond :)

Answer (score 0):

Scott hit the nail on the head.

```
Sub Test() 

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/analystestimates" ' should work for any URL
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

. . .  YOUR CODE HERE  . . .

End With
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=sbux&ql=1"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

    . . .  YOUR CODE HERE  . . .

End Sub
```